# How can I stop the service of another app in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, scheduler

On my device runs a service in an app (its not my app and I cannot uninstall it and my device is not rooted) that is always draining power. I can stop that service in my devices application settings but is there a way to stop it programatically, so I don't have to do that manually all the time ?

Could maybe something like **stopService(...);** work ?

Is there maybe a way to change the scheduler to prevent the restarts of the service ?

```
"W/ActivityManager(178): Scheduling restart of crashed service xxxx in 5000ms
```

Comment: If rooted, you *can* uninstall using Titanium Backup.

Comment: My device is not rooted. I should have added that.

Comment: Out of interest, which service is it that drains enough battery for you to want to attempt this?

Comment: If this is in fact the situation, your best option is probably to return the phone as defective merchandise.

Answer (score 1):

Get the process id of that particular application and then

android.os.Process.killProcess(processIdKillService)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a long shot (I've never tried it):

1. Create a `Context` instance for that app using [`Context.createPackageContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
2. Use it to stop the service via [`Context.stopService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29)